# Sending emails through the Microsoft Graph API started throwing 500

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADFkZDdjMWM0LTg2MzYtNGI4ZC1hNDAzLWY2NDljZmZmZDM4YQBGAAAAAAAy50dDcjLxRroxR16zN80WBwAqP1cdrk5dTLdAWYlr7M8QAAAAAAEPAAAqP1cdrk5dTLdAWYlr7M8QAAChu4WSAAA=/send

Suddenly started throwing this now (first it was seen on the beta endpoints. Now it is coming on v1.0 as well

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "eecf9817-1c44-4fa5-aabb-f975f8496484",
      "date": "2016-09-25T09:16:43"
    }
  }
}

Comment: This sounds more like a question to be addressed to the Microsoft Graph support.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Microsoft engineers do Graph support here.